# Using DefaultDict(List) with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, defaultdict

I'm trying to accomplish this with Python 3.6.1, Pycharm 2017.1.3., Openpyxl 2.4.7, and Excel 2016.

Here is my dataset:

Sheet1:

```
productnum|keyword1|keyword2
0001      |red     |big     
0001      |blue    |red
0001      |large   |blue
0002      |green   |
0002      |small   |blue
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
productnum|keyword1      |keyword2    |combinedkeywords
0001      |red;blue;large|big;red;blue|red;blue;large;big
0002      |green;small   |blue        |green;small;blue
```

I have been informed that DefaultDict(List) is a good way to accomplish this task. Here is what I've tried thus far to do so:

```
for rownum in range(1,maxRow):
     partnum = str(sheet1.cell(row=rownum, column=1).value)
     keyword1 = str(sheet1.cell(row=rownum, column=3).value)


    s = [(partnum,keyword1)]
          print(s)
          d = defaultdict(list)
          for k, v in s:
          d[k].append(v)
```

But what I end up isn't exactly what I need, coming out as something like:

```
[('0001', 'red']
[('0001', 'blue']
```

And so on.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can accomplish this using defaultdict(list)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This here is not a direct answer to your question about `defaultdict`, but rather an alternative solution method. You could use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to process your data. The code below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read excel table into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx')

# Aggregate unique keywords for each product number
func = lambda x: tuple(x.unique())
df2 = df.groupby('productnum').agg(func)

# Create column for all keyword combinations
func = lambda x: tuple(set(x.keyword1) | set(x.keyword2))
df2['combinedkeywords'] = df2.apply(func, axis=1)

# Print result dataframe to screen and also to excel file
print(df2)
df2.to_excel('workbook2.xlsx')
```

produces this as output:

```
                      keyword1          keyword2           combinedkeywords
productnum
1           (red, blue, large)  (big, red, blue)    (red, large, blue, big)
2               (green, small)       (nan, blue)  (nan, green, blue, small)
```